# Selecionar por padrão o "Cancelar" no alert

Tags: javascript

Como todos sabem o **confirm do JS** vai mostrar um **alert** com o texto informado e as opções **CANCELAR** e **OK**. E logo assim, o **OK** está sempre selecionado e isso por via atrapalha (em meu caso pelo menos). Existe a possibilidade de manter o **CANCELAR** selecionado ao invés do **OK**?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar esse plugin

http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

E fazer um código assim.

```
$.prompt('Example 4',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }, focus: 1 });
```

Fonte

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699582/javascript-how-to-select-cancel-by-default-in-confirm-box?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Amigo isso não é possível com javascript. Neste caso sugiro você criar seu próprio popUp. O bootstrap oferece uns alertas bacanas e simples de serem implementados.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode fazer isso. O foco da opção padrão é mesmo o OK. No lugar do **confirm** você pode utilizar a biblioteca abaixo.

http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert

Além de resolver o seu problema, melhora a usabilidade de seu site, ja que produz algo mais amigável.